# how to configure Sinatra to accept more option parameters?

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I'm using Sinatra for a desktop app that runs on local host. When I start it up, I want to pass it an option like this `ruby mysinatra.rb -first_name="My Name"` However, I keep getting invalid option error. I think I'm getting it because Sinatra itself accepts options for things like port. For example, when I run `ruby mysinatra.rb -h`, the output I get (see below) is all the options that Sinatra accepts.

Note: The option that is going to be passed in is something that changes every time the application is going to be run, so it has to be convenient. It can't be hard-coded into a file.

This is the output from running `ruby mysinatra.rb`

```
Usage: main [options]
    -p port                          set the port (default is 4567)
    -s server                        specify rack server/handler
    -q                               turn on quiet mode (default is off)
    -x                               turn on the mutex lock (default is off)
    -e env                           set the environment (default is development)
    -o addr                          set the host (default is (env == 'development' ? 'localhost' : '0.0.0.0'))
```

Comment: You can pass it as env like `FIRST_NAME_"My name" Ruby mysinatra.rb` and then access it in your code with `ENV['FIRST_Name']` but given it’s a web server and it can accept input from the internet it’s a pretty weird thing to do

Comment: What is it you’re trying to achieve?

Comment: @MikeSzyndel I'm making a browser based application for developers who will only run it on their local computer. It needs a webserver to host javascript files. But it's not going to be used like a website that you run once and leave open. Rather like a command line tool that you pass an option to each time it's run and (ideal use case) you might run it four or five times an hour with a different option passed. i.e. it analyzes the option that's being passed and presents the results in the javascript file.  I hope that's clear.

Comment: I'm not sure why someone voted to close this question without an explanation? @MikeSzyndel ```FIRST_NAME_"My name" Ruby mysinatra.rb```   is not valid code for setting an environment variable. Setting an environment variable from instructions I've seen is a lot more involved than what I was hoping for.

Comment: You need to pass paramaters accessible from ARGV or ENV if you're running a standard Sinatra app.

Comment: Sorry I was typing it from mobile and made a typo. Setting an env variable is as simple as `NAME=value command`

Answer (score 2):

Two ways to do this:

1. Parse options before you `require` the Sinatra libraries. Make sure to remove any of your personal option strings from ARGV, so that regular Sinatra options still work (if that is your preference).
2. Sinatra uses the Ruby `optparse` library for its own option processing. This library accepts a string `--` to designate end of options. Therefore you could just do like this:

   ```
   ruby sinatra.rb -- --first_name="My Name"
   ```

   If you look at ARGV now, it would look like this:

   ```
   ["--", "--first_name=My Name"]
   ```

   From here you can do any ARGV option processing you like.